lcov process stuck in flock
I am using gcc-10.3.0 and lcov 1.15. While processing the .gcda files I found my lcov (geninfo) process is stuck while acquiring the lock. My data is over the NFS. Here are the details/output.
strace: Process 51307 attached
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {l_type=F_RDLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}```

Operating System: RHEL7

I found this issue especially when I am running large number of testcases to generate the coverage report (>30-40k)


Suggest to update to a newer lcov.  If there is still a problem after that:  then a testcase which illustrates the issue is very likely the next step.
